# How add my text to function that sends my window to print

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex

I work in an apex oracle. I created a link and added a dynamic action with Javascript to it. With the help of this action, I print the table that is in my window. It works, in the window I see the table that I need, but I want to add under the table of words "Signature ______" but I cannot do that. I will be grateful for your help)

```html
//// Collapse Left Navigation Bar If It Was Expanded ////
var navCollapsed = 0;
if ($("body").hasClass("js-navExpanded")) {
    $("#t_Button_navControl").click();
    navCollapsed = 1;
};
setTimeout(3000);



//////// Hide ////////

//Hide Navigation Bar List
$("#t_Header").hide();

//Hide Navigation Menu
$("#t_Body_nav").hide();

//Hide Breadcrumb
$("#t_Body_title").hide();

//Hide Content Offset
$("#t_Body_content_offset").hide();

//Hide Report Column Edit Link
$(".apex-edit-page").hide();

//Hide Report Download Links
$(".t-Report-links").hide();

//Hide Buttons
$(".t-Button").hide();

//Hide Footer
$(".t-Footer").hide();



//////// Browser Print ////////
window.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an element before window.print() and append it under the table of words, or the element that you want.

Example:

```
var signatureDiv = document.createElement('H3');
signatureDiv.innerHTML = 'Signature ___________________';

document.body.appendChild(signatureDiv);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it puts the "Signature ____________" on the second page and the table on the first